# How can I print an odd and even lines as a column using AWK?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have an out put from R and I need to print the out put properly. I need to print odd and even rows as respective columns.

Original file

```
4             4             4             4             4 
-3.592311e+00 -3.360352e+00 -3.063397e+00 -3.660137e+00  8.053911e+00 
            4             4             4             4             4 
 1.077868e+01 -2.455155e+00  6.214082e+00  5.311552e+00  5.311552e+00
       10            10            10            10            10 
-4.394679e+00 -2.527588e+00  7.716434e+00  5.001199e+00  2.653916e+00 
           10            10            10            10            10 
 3.673181e+00  3.721885e+00  3.464234e+00 -4.363173e-01  6.849429e-01
```

Desired output

```
    4 -3.592311e+00
    4 -3.360352e+00
    4 -3.063397e+00
    4 -3.660137e+00
    4 8.053911e+00
    4 1.077868e+01
    4 -2.455155e+00
    4 6.214082e+00
    4 5.311552e+00
    4 5.311552e+00
   10 -4.394679e+00
   10 -2.527588e+00
   10 7.716434e+00
   10 5.001199e+00
   10 2.653916e+00 
   10 3.673181e+00
   10 3.721885e+00 
   10 3.464234e+00
   10 -4.363173e-01
   10 6.849429e-01
```

I used the following code but it couldn't give me what i want

```
awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) f[i] = f[i] " " $i ; if (NF > n) n = NF } END { for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) sub(/^ */, "", f[i]) ; for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) print f[i] } ' file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an awk approach, which relies on splitting even and odd lines into appropriate arrays.

```
$ awk 'NR%2 !=0 {split($0,col1)}; NR%2 == 0 {split($0,col2); for (i=1;i<=length(col1);i++) print col1[i],col2[i]};' inpu>
4 -3.592311e+00
4 -3.360352e+00
4 -3.063397e+00
4 -3.660137e+00
4 8.053911e+00
4 1.077868e+01
4 -2.455155e+00
4 6.214082e+00
4 5.311552e+00
4 5.311552e+00
10 -4.394679e+00
10 -2.527588e+00
10 7.716434e+00
10 5.001199e+00
10 2.653916e+00
10 3.673181e+00
10 3.721885e+00
10 3.464234e+00
10 -4.363173e-01
10 6.849429e-01
```

The way this works is quite simple. `NR % 2 != 0` tells us that the line is odd, and `NR % 2 == 0` is even. In odd lines we only split the whole line into array. In even lines, we split and print out both arrays on item-by-item basis. This process repeats in alternating fashion till the last line is reached.

This can be improved, of course, space between columns can be increased and such. The approach isn't bulletproof and is tailored to this specific case, where number of fields is the same in each line of the original file

Comment: NIce answer. To simplify a bit: `awk '{split($0,col1); getline; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print col1[i], $i}'`